# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**Выдает ошибку в линии где return $this->urban();**

```
public function toggleBan($value)
{
    is($value == null)
    {
        return $this->unban();
    }

    return $this->ban();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is` поменяйте на `if` и будет всё чики-брики.